Как импортировать функцию из другой папки Python
У меня такая структура файлов:
home/
    Bot/
       app/
          handlers.py
    Parser_news/
       news_parser.py
    Parser_for_ML/
       parser_ml 

Как импортировать условный модуль currency из файла news_parser.py и svecha из файла parser_ml?
Пробовал вот так:
from Parser_news.news_parser import currency 
from Parser_for_ML.parser_for_ml import svecha 

и вот так:
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..\Parser_news'))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..\Parser_for_ML'))

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить

а вот так пробовали?
import sys
sys.path.append('../Parser_news')
sys.path.append('../Parser_for_ML')

from name  import ....

Сейчас попробовал, не помогло. На сколько я понимаю писать from news_parser import ... ? Просто мне даже не выводит возможные названия при импорте

@Artem37 нет, я имел ввиду что у Вас не верно был прописан путь к файлу. sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('..\Parser_news')) - не верно. sys.path.append('../Parser_news') - верно. Вам нужно почитать про абсолютные и относительные пути, тогда у Вас все встанет на свои места). Вот мануал https://desktop.arcgis.com/ru/arcmap/latest/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm

Все равно не помогло) Python не видит нужного файла, я уже прописал как вы скинули. Попробовал, как писали в статье через двойной \ все равно не вышло. И не совсем понятно кстати, в статье написано, что UNIX языки принимают как раз \ и \, а вы писали, что так не верно. Или я что то перепутал?

@Artem37 на самом то деле, все просто... Попробуй еще раз самостоятельно, вот пример - https://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html
